# Raised flag without any action

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

I have already raised about 24 flags and 13 of them marked helpful (although some of them marked declined because those question/answers already closed, not because of my wrong flag) and only about 5 of them declined and 6 of them are still open, even a flag that I raised about two years ago:

[image: Picture of active flag]

Shouldn't my flag mark as helpful or declined by now? This specific flag is not my problem. My problem is why no one ever reviewed my raised flag?

Although it is not important, here are the links to this two questions: [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309071/issue-related-to-document-getelementbyclassname-in-javascript) and [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337900/getting-child-elements-of-an-element).

Just to make it more clear, I didn't mind if my flag is declined. The important thing for me is that no one did anything, and it is just one of my active flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your flag is a "duplicate question" flag.

This is fed into the close review queue which currently has over 10,000 questions in it - and has had for some time. This queue can be seen by all users with more than 3k rep - though not all users do reviews.

Your flag will only be marked "helpful" when the question is closed - which requires 5 votes (or one from someone with a gold tag badge in one of the question's original tags).

It's therefore going to take sometime before your flag is processed.

Comment: This active flags didnt count in my flags? I just whant to flag a post and when I click in flag it said 10 flag remaining, I wonder maybe I if didnt have any active flags I'll have more remaining flags.

Comment: @AliAmiri: that count is your *daily flag limit*. The flag that is active doesn't count against that limit, because you did not flag it *today*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters tnx :)

Comment: Psst. It gets marked helpful if it gets closed for any reason *or* if someone casts a close vote for the same close reason as you flagged (in this case, duplicate).